# MySQL View Creation

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
parking_lot
    id
    name


parking_spot
    id
    parking_lot_id
    available
```

I would like to create a view that looks like this:

```
parking_lot_view
    id
    name
    num_spots_available
```

What would the query to create this view be for a MySQL DB?

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple query, so I assume you are pretty new to MySQL and databases.  You should definitely try to understand how this works and study up on the subject:

```
create view parking_lot_view as
    select pl.id, pl.name, sum(available) as NumAvailable
    from parking_spot ps join
         parking_lot pl
         on ps.parking_lot_id = pl.id
    group by pl.id, pl.name;
```

This assumes that `available` is `1` when available and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a view, first start by creating a Select SQL Statement joining whatever tables you need. Then you just add "CREATE VIEW  AS" at the beginning and Execute.

In your specific case, this should do the trick (I assumed 'available' is an Integer that contains 0 for unavailable and 1 for available, since you do not specify that in your question):

```
CREATE VIEW parking_lot_view AS
select L.id, L.name, count(*) available_spots
from parking_lot L inner join parking_spot S on S.parking_lot_id = L.id
where S.available <> 0
group by L.id, L.name
```